What is the name for contrast coefficients where the difference between the coefficients = 1?
I am wondering if there is a name for the type of contrast coding where the difference between the terms is equal to 1. Let me illustrate with some fake data (using R code, apologies)
Two groups, with the mean of group b being 3 greater than the mean of group a.
set.seed(1234)
df_2groups <- data.frame(group = factor(rep(letters[1:2],each=10)),
                         score = round(x = c(rnorm(10,5,1), rnorm(10,8,1)),
                                       digits = 2))

head(df_2groups)

#   group score
# 1     a  3.79
# 2     a  5.28
# 3     a  6.08
# 4     a  2.65
# 5     a  5.43
# 6     a  5.51

With treatment coding [0,1] the intercept is the mean of group a and the group coefficient is the difference in means between group b and group a (mean group b minus mean group a).
summary(lm(score ~ group, df_2groups))

# Coefficients:
#             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
# (Intercept)   4.6170     0.3268  14.127 3.50e-11 ***
# groupb        3.2640     0.4622   7.062 1.38e-06 ***

Now if we specify sum-to-zero contrasts [-1,1] (the "contr.sum" contrasts in R) the  intercept becomes the grand mean - the mean scores across both groups - and the coefficient is the difference between group b and the grand mean (mean group b minus grand mean)
summary(lm(score ~ group, df_2groups, contrasts = list(group = c(-1,1))))

# Coefficients:
#             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
# (Intercept)   6.2490     0.2311  27.040 5.00e-16 ***
# group1        1.6320     0.2311  -7.062 1.38e-06 ***

To get the difference in means between groups returned accurately in the regression output accurately we need to use simple coding (as defined here), which we do by subtracting 1/nlevels from the treatment coding.
summary(lm(score ~ group, df_2groups, contrasts = list(group = c(-.5,.5))))

# Coefficients:
#             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
# (Intercept)   6.2490     0.2311  27.040 5.00e-16 ***
# group1        3.2640     0.4622  -7.062 1.38e-06 ***

The second and third contrasts schemes are both "sum-to-zero" contrasts because they sum to zero.
It occurs to me that what treatment coding and simple coding have in common is that the difference between the two contrast coefficients is 1.
Is there a name for this type of contrast: that is where the difference between the coefficients is 1?
